# Laravel API only accessible via vpn

Tags: php, api, laravel, vpn

We are building the API that will used by other application to read/write data on from our application.

**E.g:** `www.example.com/getPayments/useid`

***The requirement***: the above API should only be accessible via VPN so someone can't call it from the web.

So how can I make some routes in our application to only be accessible via VPN in Laravel .

Comment: I dont understand the question - you dont host it on a webserver that is callable from the web but only in your local LAN.

Comment: @Xatenev It's on a web server , anyone can access all routes from the web for now, I  don't want  those API to be accessible publicly  on the web

Comment: This is very easy to do but is typically done at the HTTP server (Apache, Nginx) or server OS levels. Is there a specific reason you want to do this access control within Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing some middleware to restrict access to certain routes based on the IP address of your visitor should work for you, so long as the IP address of the VPN has been included in the HTTP headers of the request or is available to PHP through another `$_SERVER` variable. You'll need to inspect the headers of the HTTP request that is sent to find the one that contains the IP address of your VPN, then use this within your middleware.

You could either write a lightweight middleware component to do this, or use an existing package to whitelist only the VPN's IP address for the routes that you want to protect.

[Firewall](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/firewall) is an existing Laravel service provider that can help you with this.

Comment: Thanks David , I think Firewall is the right way go , I am using it now . Thanks for the recommendation